# $ \sum n (exp(\frac{1}{n^2})-1) $

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that 
$$ \sum n (exp(\frac{1}{n^2})-1) $$ diverges

I think we must use the comparasion test, but I couldnt find a fuction that is less than this one and goes to infinite.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the range of n?

Answer (score 3):

It's enough to bound it from below by $e^{\frac{1}{k^2}}>1+\frac{1}{k^2}$ and compare to Harmonic series.

Comment: Indeed, but how to shpw this inequality?

Comment: 1) Taylor series, 2) consider the function $f(x) = e^x - 1 -x$ and show it increases for all $x>0$

Comment: I notedthe second soluction, thanks

Comment: You are welcome